# Loading spinner not showing up in React JS web app

Tags: reactjs, spinner, react-bootstrap, loading

I'm trying to include a loading spinner in my react web app to show the loading animation when the API is fetching the data. Below is the code:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner';

export default function Home() {
  const [bookInput, setBookInput] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  async function onSubmit(event) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/generate", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ book: bookInput }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw data.error || new Error(`Request failed with status ${response.status}`);
      }
      setResult(data.result);
      setIsLoading(false);
      //setBookInput("");
    } catch(error) {
      // Consider implementing your own error handling logic here
      console.error(error);
      alert(error.message);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Quickread</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/book.png" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <img src="/book.png" className={styles.icon} />
        <h2>QuickRead</h2>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="book"
            placeholder="Enter a Book Title"
            value={bookInput}
            onChange={(e) => setBookInput(e.target.value)}
          />
           {isLoading ? <Spinner animation="border" role="status"/> : <input type="submit" value="Summarize" />}
        </form>
        <div className={styles.result}>{result}</div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using the react-bootstrap library for the loading spinner but not sure why is it not showing when the API is fetching the data. Appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Comment: Try to put console.log(isLoading) before render to see if isLoading state is changing to true.

Comment: I usually create a function for the API and run that function in useEffect Hook and then I open my chrome dev tool to check the state values. I recommend you debug the values step by step. The code looks fine to me.

Comment: The react code looks correct. Have you checked if the spinner node is visible in the dom ? Might be a css related issue ? Have you imported bootstrap css ?